# Connected components of analytic subset $Z$ of a complex manifold $M$ are open in $Z$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, complex-geometry, analytic-functions

I am reading the book *Introduction to complex analytic geometry* by Stanislaw Lojasiewicz. In Chapter II, we have that a subset $Z$ of a complex manifold $M$ is called an *analytic subset* of $M$ if every point of $M$ has an open neighbourhood $U$ such that the set $Z \cap U$ is a globally analytic subset of $U$ i.e. there exist finitely many holomorphic functions $f_1, \dotsc, f_k$ in $U$ such that

$Z \cap U =\{x \in U \ : \ f_1(x)=\dotsc =f_k(x)=0\}.$

Is it true that the connected components of $Z$ are analytic subsets of $M$ and is open in $Z$?

I think saw some result in this direction in the book but it seems confusing. Any good reference for the same would be a great help ! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You may try to show that $Z$ is [locally connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_connected_space), which is equivalent to saying the connected components are open.